# SilverStripe 3 Filtering / Filtering Out DataObjects in a Function

Tags: php, function, count, filtering, silverstripe

I've found some examples of filtering but nothing clear enough to answer my question. I have the following function to get my grand children pages. I'm trying to count them but only **if** they meet certain criteria. In my case **if they do not** have X,Y,Z then include them in the count.

In other words would like to add a list / array of arguments to the function that if ANY are true then don't include them and filter them out. For example if `DealerOnly = true` ignore.

I thought about doing this in the template and using if / else but the count won't display like this so I haven't gone down that route.

Alternative methods welcome.

```
<% loop $GrandChildren %>$Count<% end_loop %>
```

Possible help:
http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/data-model-questions/show/23507

Docs here: (not quite what I need though)
https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/

My function which returns my grandchild pages.

```
public function getGrandChildren() {
    $ids = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID))->getIDList();
    $grandChildren = Page::get()->filter(array(
        'ParentID' => $ids
    ));

    return $grandChildren;
}
```

In my template which counts all the pages

```
$GrandChildren.Count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I didn't get the other answers to work. I found out you can filter in the template.

```
$GrandChildren.Filter('DealerOnly','0').Count
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can manipulate your `DataList` like you want, e.g.

```
public function getGrandChildren() {
    $ids = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID))->getIDList();
    $grandChildren = Page::get()
        ->filter(array(
            'ParentID' => $ids
        ))
        ->exclude(array('DealerOnly' => true));

    return $grandChildren;
}
```

See API docs for [`DataList::exclude`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_exclude) and [docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/)

If you want to exclude if any of more columns in the database is true, you have to use the `:not` searchfilter modifier as unfortunately there is no `excludeAny()` function.

```
->filter(array('DealerOnly:not' => true))
->filter(array('Foo:not' => 'Bar'))
```

Comment: It does not seem to have any effect.. There are no errors or anything. It just does not exclude anything... I've tried with 'Title' too which would exclude everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ->exclude, so for you DataList...

```
$grandChildren->exclude(array(
  'DealerOnly' => true
));
```