# SilverStripe 3: Solution for displaying a filtered count of siblings grandchild pages?

Tags: php, function, templates, filter, silverstripe

UPDATE:

I realised I had the GrandChildren function duplicated on Page.php as well so even removing the function from StockistAreaHolderPage.php meant that $GrandChildren.Count still worked but without filtering of course. If I add the filter part to the Page.php function its breaks the site, I assume as the Dealer is missing in the database from other pages.
So I need to rename my functions for the StockistAreaHolderPage.php and / or the ProductTypePage.php to say GrandchildrenStock, but following the answers I've been given and changing the function names and then using $GrandchildrenStock.Count in my template doesn't display anything.

**I'm a bit lost now! I just want to loop another page type from my current page then count its grandchildren.**

---

UPDATED QUESTION here (original below):

I've just realised I missed a big part of the code. Which may change it a lot.
I'm actually working on page X (StockistAreaHolder.ss). I'm then accessing a siblings child Y (ProductTypePage.ss).
Then listing / looping these Y children. I’m then attempting to count each Y’s grandchildren and have then filtered.

I was using this function in my page StockistAreaHolder.php to access the Y pages:

```
function ProductTypes()
{
$producttypes = ProductTypePage::get();
return $producttypes ? $producttypes : false;
}
```

Then looping them in my template and attempting to access a filtered list of their grandchildren:

```
<% loop $ProductTypes %>
<li class="filter $URLSegment">
    <a id="$URLSegment" href="#">$Title ($GrandChildren.Count)</a>
</li>
```

This works and shows the count but the filter is not working. This is the GrandChildren function from StockistAreaHolder.php with the filter that counts but does not exclude the pages which meet the filter requirement.

```
public function getGrandChildren() {
$ids = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID))->getIDList();
$grandChildren = Page::get()
->filter(array('DealerOnly' => false));

return $grandChildren;
}
```

What’s the best way yo access these pages and display a filtered count next to their grandparents title?

---

---

ORIGINAL Question

I have a page (A) with children (B's) each of these children has children (C's).
On page A I want to display a list of B's with a count next to each which counts the C's belonging to B.

I can do this with a function to get all the children's children and then $Count:

```
$Grandchildren.Count
```

This is my grandChildren function in my if that helps. StockistAreaHolderPage.php :

```
public function getGrandChildren() {
$ids = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID))->getIDList();
$grandChildren = Page::get()->filter(array(
'ParentID' => $ids
));

return $grandChildren;
}
```

but I want the count to filter / exclude some of the C pages depending on if an option / boolean is true on the page.

I did start this question here: [SilverStripe 3 Filtering / Filtering Out DataObjects in a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099701/silverstripe-3-filtering-filtering-out-dataobjects-in-a-function)
And the answer so far was:

```
public function getGrandChildren() {
$ids = Page::get()->filter(array('ParentID' => $this->ID))->getIDList();
$grandChildren = Page::get()
->filter(array(
'ParentID' => $ids
))
->exclude(array('DealerOnly' => true));

return $grandChildren;
}
```

but i think this method doesnt work as its not a data object I'm excluding but a page.. And is therefor a different question. This any only counts all the pages still.

Maybe this is the wrong / complicated way to go about it. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I understand what you're looking for I think, but you've confused me at the end. Is it pages we are dealing with here, or a DataObject. I can't see anything wrong with the code block you have initially.. It seems you've asked the same question. The second code block above is getting all pages where the parent is the current page and then looking for all pages where the parent ID is then in the $ids, excluding DealerOnly. So using $getGrandChildren.Count in your template should work, in theory.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have updated my questions as I forgot to add its accessing a sibling page.

Comment: Okay, so now let me clarify.. the count you are wanting to display is the total number of grandchildren for the current $ProductType loop item?

Comment: Yes, but with a filter included. $GrandChildren.Count works inside the loop item but the filter does not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well in your case invoking <% loop $ProductTypes %> passes the Controller to the active ProductTypePage object, hence on each iteration you only then need to use $Title to return the Title, for example.

So, within your ProductTypePage.php file, create a method within ProductTypePage_Controller class called getGrandChildren. With this inside it...

```
public function getGrandChildren() {

    return Page::get()->filter(array(
        "ParentID" => $this->ID,
        "DealerOnly" => 0
    ));

}
```

What this is doing, is calling getGrandChildren() on each loop using the data from the current row in the DataObject. So $this->ID would equal the ID of the parent item. Then call $GrandChildren.Count within your template as you are currently doing.

This is the best way to achieve what you're looking for and should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've found time to come back to this now, I still can't get this to work.. I've updated my question.